# Looking for a suggestion with MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a gallery which contains images with IDs. Some of images has multiple categories like 102,120. But some images has only one category like 102. I needed to exclude listing of those images with only category 102. So mysql query for that looks as follows, and it is working fine.

```
SELECT g.id, g.category FROM `galleries` g WHERE g.display=1 AND g.category NOT LIKE "102"';
```

I need to exclude one more category 84, but some images has two category ids 84,154.

So i have tried the following query,

```
SELECT g.id, g.category FROM `galleries` g WHERE g.display=1 AND g.category NOT LIKE "102" AND g.category NOT LIKE "%84%"';
```

I need to list images contains category 154 which are sharing category 84 also. But the above query not listing many images that contains category 154 also because they are sharing the category 84 too.

I need suggestion to list all images except 102 & 84 while displaying 154 and others.

Comment: I have no problem with 102, I need to exclude all images of category 84 also while listing 154 which are sharing both categorys 84,154.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

I would expect SQL like this:

```
select g.image_id
from galleries g
where g.display = 1
group by g.image_id
having sum(category = 102) = 0 and
       sum(category = 84) = 0;
```

That is, I would expect `id` to uniquely identify each row in `galleries` and another column, say `image_id`, to be the id for an "image".

Comment: I think the above query excludes categories 102 and 84. What about images with multiple categories like 154,84. The above query don't exclude these right? I only need to include category 154 even if it is sharing the category 84.

Comment: `sum(category = 102)`: are you adding booleans? Is this MySQL-specific dialect?

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . The question is specifically about MySQL.

Comment: Yes, I meant I didn't know MySQL was able to add booleans a ints. Just tried it in 5,x and 8.x and works. Though I don't like the syntax, I can't argue is way shorter than what I would have written.